# What is this Number?

Tags: mathematics

N is a number where each digit is divisible by its place, for example:

> 1527

1 has to be divisible by 1, 5 divisible by 2, 2 divisible by 3, and 7 divisible by 4.

Additionally, N must be divisible by all of its digits.

It has to be at least 5 digits long, and have at least 3 different digits.

Does N exist? Is there more than 1 number that fits N? If so is there a pattern? Give a few examples.

Comment: The identity that $n$ divides $n$ makes this very, very easy.

Comment: @Emrakul Exactly what do you mean by that...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> If such an N exists, it is at least 5 digits long, so it has a 2<sup>nd</sup> digit and a 5<sup>th</sup> digit.
>  The second digit must be divisible by 2, and the 5<sup>th</sup> digit must be divisible by 5.
>  N is divisible by both of these, so it must be divisible by 10.
>  Then the last digit of N is 0.
>  But no positive number can be divisible by 0, so N cannot exist.